# rearrange name order in pandas column

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas, split, apply

**Background**

I have the following `df`

```
import pandas as pd
df= pd.DataFrame({'Text' : ['Hi', 'Hello', 'Bye'], 
                          'P_ID': [1,2,3], 
                          'Name' :['Bobby,Bob Lee Brian', 'Tuck,Tom T ', 'Mark, Marky '],
                         })

              Name     P_ID Text
0   Bobby,Bob Lee Brian 1   Hi
1   Tuck,Tom T          2   Hello
2   Mark, Marky         3   Bye
```

**Goal**

1) rearrange the `Name` column from e.g. `Bobby,Bob Lee Brian` to `Bob Lee Brian Bobby`

2) create new column `Rearranged_Name`

**Desired Output**

```
           Name        P_ID Text  Rearranged_Name
0   Bobby,Bob Lee Brian 1   Hi    Bob Lee Brian Bobby 
1   Tuck,Tom T          2   Hello Tom T Tuck
2   Mark, Marky         3   Bye   Marky Mark
```

**Question**

How do I achieve my desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with values before and after `,`, `\s*` means there are optionally whitespace after `,`:

```
df['Rearranged_Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace(r'(.+),\s*(.+)', r'\2 \1')
print (df)
    Text  P_ID                 Name      Rearranged_Name
0     Hi     1  Bobby,Bob Lee Brian  Bob Lee Brian Bobby
1  Hello     2           Tuck,Tom T           Tom T Tuck
2    Bye     3          Mark, Marky           Marky Mark
```

Or use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) for helper `DataFrame` and join columns together:

```
df1 = df['Name'].str.split(',\s*', expand=True)
df['Rearranged_Name'] = df1[1] + ' ' + df1[0]
```